# Kendo Grid - resize column causing grid height to be altered.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-grid

See the example here:
http://dojo.telerik.com/uFuYa/2

When you resize the column header (reduce the width) it's pushing the whole grid downwards. Also when you lower the column header width, then increase it, it reduces the height of the whole grid. Same issue happens when virtual scrolling is disabled. Is there any workaround to stop this happening? The content section (data section) seems to just push the footer down. Even if the footer is fixed, the content section still pushes past it.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended all Grid rows to be of equal height, so that the virtual scrolling functionality works as expected:

[Virtual scrolling - Kendo UI documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#virtual-scrolling)

You can set the CSS **white-space** property to *nowrap* for the Grid header and regular cells:

[Modified dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/uFuYa/3)

Comment: Ah, I see. I was hoping there would be a way to do this without text wrap for column headers. Thanks for the help.